# Marshmallow Schema and Class Inheritance

Tags: python, marshmallow

I am using Marshmallow for the first time and unfortunately could not find an answer on the internet.

There are two classes, one inherits from the other.
Both should be serialisable and deserialisable.
After deserialisation they should be available again as Python objects.
Therefore I use the `post_load` decorator.
But it seems that this causes problems.
In the minimal working example below I get the following exception: `type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not Bicycle`.

One could now look for the attribute `amount_of_tires` and, if necessary, pass on the data.
But this does not feel like the right solution.

Is there a best practise to solve this problem?

```py
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
from marshmallow.decorators import post_load


class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, weight):
        self.weight = weight


class VehicleSchema(Schema):
    weight = fields.Float()

    @post_load
    def make_vehicle(self, data, **kwargs) -> Vehicle:
        return Vehicle(**data)


class Bicycle(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, weight, amount_of_tires):
        Vehicle.__init__(self, weight=weight)
        self.amount_of_tires = amount_of_tires


class BicycleSchema(VehicleSchema):
    amount_of_tires = fields.Integer()

    @post_load
    def make_bicycle(self, data, **kwargs) -> Bicycle:
        return Bicycle(**data)


my_bicycle = Bicycle(weight=10, amount_of_tires=2)


schema = BicycleSchema()
json_string = schema.dumps(my_bicycle)

deserialised_my_bicycle = schema.loads(json_string)
print(deserialised_my_bicycle)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `make_vehicle` and `make_bicycle` are registered as `post_load` hooks, and so they are getting called one after the other. When `make_vehicle` is called, `make_bicycle` is already called, and so `type(data) == Bicycle`, hence the error you see.

I recommend the following solution:

```py
class VehicleSchema(Schema):
    model_class = Vehicle

    weight = fields.Float()

    @post_load
    def make_vehicle(self, data, **kwargs) -> Vehicle:
        return type(self).model_class(**data)

class BicycleSchema(VehicleSchema):
    model_class = Bicycle
    amount_of_tires = fields.Integer()
```

To get more accurate type hints with this solution - one can use `Generic` and `TypeVar` on the base `VehicleSchema` class (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic).

Comment: This is a nice idea.
There is small error in your example. I had to change `model_class` to `instance_model`.
And I would suggest to change the function name from `make_vehicle` to `deserialise` and remove the type hint, cause it can now be a vehicle or a bicycle in the end. 
Am I right?

Comment: @unlimitedfox Well spotted I've updated. In this example the `make_vehicle` and return type `Vehicle` are appropriate, as the inheritance implies that a `Bicycle` is a `Vehicle`. As I noted, the type hints could be more specific by using generics - but I think that would distract from the answer somewhat.

Comment: I think at the return statement we have to replace `instance_model` with `model_class`